# stargazer output: how to omit one value of as.factor(variable)?

Tags: r, stargazer

I have a model like this

```
model <-lm(outcome ~ var0 + var1 + as.factor(var2))
```

with `var2` taking the values `A`, `B`, and `C`. I create the output with `stargazer`. I would like to omit `var0` and `as.factor(var2)A` from the output. I couldn't achieve this; I tried:

```
stargazer(model, type = "html", out = "./output.html",
    omit = c("var0", "var2")) # omits ALL var2 entries

stargazer(model, type = "html", out = "./output.html",
    omit = c("var0", "as.factor(var2)B")) # omits no var2 entry in addition to the base category (A)
```

Can someone point me to the solution? (**N.B.**: this is not what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368917/omit-output-of-a-factor-variable-in-stargazer) question asks, which wants to omit ALL entries of the variables.)

The second example results in [image: this] output. But I would like the entry marked in yellow to be omitted.

Comment: using `stargazer` 5.2.2 and `R` 3.6.1 your second example works for me (BTW you're missing a comma in the examples)

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the help; I fixed the comma and updated the question. (Unfortunately my example was poorly chosen since the base category (here: `A`) is omitted anyway - not due to my code, however. I have adjusted my example and added a desired output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do how `stargazer` treats the `omit` argument. The documentation says that it expects a vector of regular expressions. In a regular expression, `.`, `(` and `)` are a special characters, so you have to escape them, in `R` this is done with a double backslash`\\`. So your argument becomes `omit = c("var0", "as\\.factor\\(var2\\)B")`.

```
stargazer(model, type = "html", out = "./output.html",
    omit = c("var0", "as\\.factor\\(var2\\)B"))
```

[image]